# Разница между .goga .zz1 и .goga>.zz1

Tags: css

Подскажите, в чем разница между этими строками - они обе отрабатывают свой код одинаково, так в чем тогда разница?

```css
.goga {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.goga .zz {
  color: red;
}
.goga>.zz1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="goga">
  <div class="zz">loremПсевдо-переменная $this доступна в том случае, если метод был вызван в контексте объекта. $this является ссылкой на вызываемый объект.</div>
  <div class="zz1">Обычно это тот объект, которому принадлежит вызванный метод, но может быть и другой объект, если метод был вызван статически из контекста другого</div>
  <div class="zz2">Это показано на следующих примерах:</div>
</div>
```

Comment: сделайте больше вложенность (class = goga внутрь class = bar, а в нем class=zz и сравните.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div > a` - если потомок ни во что больше не вложен.

А теперь почувствуйте разницу:

```css
div > a {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
  </h3>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </p>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

```css
div a {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
  </h3>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </p>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```